# Site-to-site VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, fortinet

We are a small business company that is based in Sydney and opened a new office in London.

```
Number of employees in Sydney office is 25 and in London is 6 employees.
```

So the traffic isn't that high. Files to be transferred are

```
Excel sheets with size of 15mb max.
```

Both locations have

```
MS server 2008 and Fortigate gateways.
```

I set up a site to site vpn but it's extremely slow. Maybe this is because

```
our upload speeds is 1Mbps only but We will 
increase the upload speed to 20 Mbps in both locations
```

but I am afraid that this will not solve the problem as the 2 locations are far from each other and the upload upgrade won't solve the problem. what's the best way to go? Shall we find a provider for the VPN? or is there another technology that can be used through internet without paying extra costs?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the geographic distance and bandwidth limitations, it may make more sense to leverage a cloud service (Microsoft Office Web Apps + Skydrive) to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: The server in Sydney is the domain controller. users in London have different access permissions and by using VPN I can give them this feature. Can I do this with MS apps ?

Comment: You should be able to give different permissions to users....http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/